# How to implement CacheLoader so that @Cacheable key is read

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache, spring-cache

In attempting to implment my own cache loader using inline refresh. This cache loaded is using RefreshAheadCacheFactory

as described at

> http://terracotta.org/documentation/4.1/bigmemorymax/api/refresh-ahead#scheduled-refresh-ahead
>
> &
>
> http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.9.0/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fco-dec_creating_a_decorator_2.html

I'm receiving an error when attempt to add my own key :

```
@Cacheable(key="myKey" , value = "myCache")
```

error is :

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'myKey' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheExpressionRootObject'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:208)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:72)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:93)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:88)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.ExpressionEvaluator.key(ExpressionEvaluator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContext.generateKey(CacheAspectSupport.java:464)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.inspectCacheables(CacheAspectSupport.java:291)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:198)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at ehcache.MyCache$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4aeb3b9c.tester(<generated>)
    at ehcache.TestEhcache.testCache(TestEhcache.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

How can I add the key "myKey" to the cache ?

I think I've setup the custom cache loader incorrectly.
How shold the loadAll method be implemented. Here is my implementation  :

```
public Map loadAll(Collection keys, Object argument) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return new HashMap<String , String>();
}
```

Should this HashMap contain the key "myKey" ?

When I customise this method :

```
public Map loadAll(Collection keys, Object argument) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Map map = new HashMap<String , String>();
 map.put("myKey", "test");

return map;
```

}

I receive same error.

All code & config :

spring-ehcache.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <cache:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager"
        p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache" />
    <bean id="ehcache"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
        p:config-location="my-ehcache.xml" />

    <bean id="myCache" class="ehcache.MyCache"></bean>
</beans>
```

my-ehcache.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">
    <defaultCache eternal="true" maxElementsInMemory="100"
        overflowToDisk="false" />
    <cache name="myCache" maxElementsInMemory="10" eternal="true"
        overflowToDisk="false">

  <cacheLoaderFactory class="MyCacheLoaderFactory" properties="myKey" 
    />

        <cacheDecoratorFactory 
            class="net.sf.ehcache.constructs.refreshahead.RefreshAheadCacheFactory"
            properties="timeToRefreshSeconds=10,
      batchSize=5,
      numberOfThreads=4,
      maximumBacklogItems=5,
      evictOnLoadMiss=true" />

    </cache>
</ehcache>
```

---

```
package ehcache;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring-ehcache.xml")
public class TestEhcache {

    @Test
    public void testCache(){

        while(true){


            long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

            System.out.println(myCache.tester());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

            System.out.println("Exc time : "+(t2-t1));
        }
    }


    @Autowired
    private MyCache myCache;

}



package ehcache;

import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;

public class MyCache {

    @Cacheable(key="myKey" , value = "myCache")
    public String tester() {

        System.out.println("in cache");
        ExpensiveOperation expensiveOperation = new ExpensiveOperation();
        String ret = expensiveOperation.doThis();

        return ret;
    }

}

package ehcache;

public class ExpensiveOperation {

    public String doThis() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "test";
    }

}

import java.util.Properties;
import net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache;
import net.sf.ehcache.loader.CacheLoader;

public class MyCacheLoaderFactory extends
        net.sf.ehcache.loader.CacheLoaderFactory {

        @Override
        public CacheLoader createCacheLoader(Ehcache cache, Properties properties) {

            return new MyCacheLoader();

        }

    }

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import net.sf.ehcache.CacheException;
import net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache;
import net.sf.ehcache.Status;
import net.sf.ehcache.loader.CacheLoader;


public class MyCacheLoader implements CacheLoader {

    public Object load(Object key) throws CacheException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return load(key, null);
    }

    public Map loadAll(Collection keys) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("in loadall");

        return loadAll(keys , null);
    }

    public Object load(Object key, Object argument) {

        System.out.println("in load");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "my object";
    }

    public Map loadAll(Collection keys, Object argument) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Map map = new HashMap<String , String>();
         map.put("myKey", "test");

        return map;
    }

    public String getName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public CacheLoader clone(Ehcache cache) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void dispose() throws CacheException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to have a look at the Spring Cache documentation, and in particular [this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-key). Your usage of the annotation is invalid, which is why you see an exception from Spring.

Second you need to really implement the `CacheLoader`. This is the class that will transform a key into a key-value pair by accessing your database, a webservice, whatever can query the system of record to get you data based on that key. This is purely application specific and depends on your use case.

Third you need to have a better look at what are the properties that you specify in the Ehcache XML, because having `myKey` there makes little sense.

And there are some other issues to fix, but understanding the first two above is critical.

Comment: Could you please provide a working code example of implementing the CacheLoader? I'm in the same boat and I'm struggling to make it work. The method annotated with @cacheable doesn't seem to be getting called after the timeToRefreshSeconds has elapsed.

Thanks!

Comment: Please open a separate question for this, tagging it Ehcache will make sure I get to it at some point.